# Java Swing : Failed to create resources from application bundle. Using Java-based resources

Tags: java, macos, swing

I tried to change `Look&Feel`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
            if (osName.contains("Mac")) {
                System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
            }
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    }
}
```

But get exception on line `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Failed to create resources from application bundle.  Using Java-based resources.
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222)
    at com.apple.resources.LoadNativeBundleAction.run(MacOSXResourceBundle.java:60)
    at com.apple.resources.LoadNativeBundleAction.run(MacOSXResourceBundle.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.apple.resources.MacOSXResourceBundle.getMacResourceBundle(MacOSXResourceBundle.java:29)
    at com.apple.resources.MacOSXResourceBundle.getMacResourceBundle(MacOSXResourceBundle.java:24)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel.initResourceBundle(AquaLookAndFeel.java:244)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(AquaLookAndFeel.java:260)    
    at com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel.getDefaults(AquaLookAndFeel.java:227)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:520)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:564)
    at org.camobap.osx.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Can someone hepl me to avoid this problem?

Update:
`jdk1.7.0_09`

Comment: [As per apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html): *When setting a property within your application (using System.setProperty), make sure that it is one of the first statements made inside of your main method. Doing so sets the property before AWT is loaded, ensuring that it takes effect.* maybe try setting it without checking the OS and see if it works

Comment: Which language is at the top position in Language & Text system preference on your mac? It seems like you have some problem with the MAC resource bundle

Comment: Runs fine on my Mac with JDK1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your error is coming from your setLookAndFeel line.  You should verify that `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` is returning what you think. You can also just check which look and feels are installed on this system with the code below:

```
    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            System.out.println(info.getName() + " - " + info.getClassName());
            //You can now set the look to the one you want with something like this:
            if ("Mac".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Forget the look and feel!           
    }
```